# What is the annotation equivalent of aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"?

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean defined in XML that looks like this:

```
<bean ... scope="workflow">
  <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>
```

I am removing this bean from the config file and marking the class that bean was instantiated from as `@Component`. From other questions about scoped proxy, I know there is a `proxyMode` on the `@Scope` annotation. In this case, if I want to emulate the above XML, is `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.NO` the same thing as `proxy-target-class="false"`? Like so:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "workflow", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.NO)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the actual answer is:

`@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)`

Citation: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/101899-annotation-equivalent-of-aop-scoped-proxy